# How to implement Windows service "keep-alive watcher"?

Tags: c#, wcf, memory-mapped-files

I have a several `Windows` services, that hosts a `WCF` services. And i want to implement a "guardian" windows service, that will watch for the other windows services, and if they stopped - restart them.

That task already completed, but i need one more feature - a possibility to stop windows service(add them to aka black list), so that "guardian" wont restart them, until windows service start manually by user. Black list also should be cleaned on windows load. The problem is that if user stopped windows service and "guardian" was stopped too at that point, the "guardian" did not know that windows service was stopped by user and it should not be restarted.

At first time i try to implement it with `Memory Mapped File`, so that block list of windows services that should not be restarted will be stored in `Memory Mapped File`. But there is a problem: a `Memory Mapped File` should be hosted by any process, and if that process stopped - a `Memory Mapped File` will be lost.

So should i use basic `file` to store "black list"?

Comment: Any storage will do.

Comment: Do you need the guardian service? - the Recovery tab allows you to set an action if the service fails. - This can restart, or run another program. This can then be removed if you are manually stopping the service.

Comment: Recovery Tab works for stops and starts, but not for hangs right? If the guardian service gets keep alives fom a client service it can detect hangs... and restart the service.